# Matching the same name in cells

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro so when there is the same value from the combobox value selected by the user, then it should output "Checked" in the cell below. Here the code that works fine:

```
    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

    Set SrchRng = Range("A3:G11")
    For Each cel In SrchRng
    If InStr(1, cel.Value, m1_day1.Value) > 0 Then
    cel.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Checked"
    End If
    Next cel
```

The problem is that when `m1_day1.Value` is '2', then the program will output "Checked" in the cell below under all the numbers that contain '2': 12, 20, 22 24 etc.

Comment: Instr looks at the whole string... is there normaly just a 2? If yes then just use `If cel.Value = m1_day1.Value Then`

Comment: @DirkReichel The values for m1_day1.Values are all integers and i'm trying to find the matching integers for them. So for m1_day1.Values it could 1,2,3,4 and etc. I tried integrating your code, but it did not work. For Each cel In SrchRng
    If cel.Value = m1_day1.Value Then
    cel.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Checked"
    End If
    Next cel

Comment: Oh... ok... thats a small problem... you could use `If InStr(1, " "&cel.Value&" ", " "&replace (m1_day1.Value,","," ")&" ") > 0 Then`

Comment: @DirkReichel Thank you so much ! That worked just beautifully ! Can you post your comment as a separate post so i can accept your solution !

Comment: look at my answer... its even better (faster)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to show it properly: (without replace)

```
If InStr(1, ","&cel.Value&",", ","&m1_day1.Value&",") > 0 Then
```

lets asume the cell has `"3,6,14,26"` it will be changed to `",3,6,14,26,"` and looking for `",6,"` => 26 wont count

Answer (score 0):

Use this. It will only replace value what you will select from combo box.

```
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range
   Set SrchRng = Range("A3:G11")
 For Each cel In SrchRng
   If cel.Value = Val(m1_day1.Value) Then
     cel.Offset(1, 0).Value = "Checked"
   End If
Next cel
```

Comment: Quote: Note: _The VAL function will stop reading the string once it encounters the first non-numeric character. This does not include spaces._ it simply wont work... and having `1 3 17` would output `1317` while `3,8,16` would get you just `3` ... i suggest that wouldnt help...